# How to avoid quotes around table aliases in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, alias, jooq

I have the following select-query creation:

```
final DSLContext create = DSL.using(..., SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

create
 .select(DSL.field("identifier"), DSL.field("name"), 
         create.selectCount()
               .from(DSL.table("person"))
               .where(DSL.field("identifier").eq(DSL.field("personOuter.identifier")))
               .asField("count"))
 .from(DSL.table("person").as("personOuter"))
```

jOOQ generates the following query:

```
select 
    identifier, 
    name, 
   (select count(*) 
    from person 
    where identifier = personOuter.identifier) as "count" 
from person as "personOuter"
```

The query should be:

```
select 
    identifier, 
    name, 
   (select count(*) 
    from person 
    where identifier = personOuter.identifier) as "count" 
from person as personOuter
```

The latter query works perfectly in PostgreSQL. The table alias should not be surrounded by quotes.

Is this a bug?

(Note that the query is pretty dumb. I am playing around with jOOQ to evaluate.)

The following "hack" works:

```
create
 .select(DSL.field("identifier"), DSL.field("name"), 
         create.selectCount()
               .from(DSL.table("person"))
               .where(DSL.field("identifier").eq(DSL.field("personOuter.identifier")))
               .asField("count"))
 .from("person as personOuter")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### A note on using the code generator

I'm assuming you have a good reason to avoid using the code generator (e.g. you work on a dynamic schema), because working with generated code prevents having to worry about such details. Plus, you get access to many advanced features, like [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), [embeddable types](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/), etc.

#### What's a string in the jOOQ API?

By default, jOOQ will wrap all your identifiers in quotes in order to be able to handle case-sensitivity correctly.

The confusing part is why this isn't done for [`DSL.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-), but only for [`Field.as(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#as-java.lang.String-). The reason for this is that jOOQ re-uses the String type for both:

- [Plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) as in `DSL.field(String)`, where the input String doesn't really represent an identifier, but an arbitrary SQL expression
- [Identifiers](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/) as in `DSL.name(String)`, where the input String represents a name / identifier. There is also [`DSL.fieldByName(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#fieldByName-java.lang.String...-) to create `Field` types composed of (schema) / table / column identifiers.

In order to remove the quotes from all generated identifiers, you can also change the [`Settings.renderNameStyle`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderNameStyle) to [`RenderNameStyle.AS_IS`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/RenderNameStyle.html#AS_IS).

[More information about `Settings` can be found here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/). And also in this blog post about [*"What’s a “String” in the jOOQ API?"*](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/03/whats-a-string-in-the-jooq-api/)