# How to alias selected columns using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to rename one of my selected fields, but it doesn't really work as expected.

This is my code

```
...
final List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<>();

fields.add(field(name("inner_id"), String.class).as("id"));
fields.add(field(name("inner_name"), String.class).as("name"));

create.select(fields).from(view).where(whereClause, whereBindings);
...
```

Which translates to:

```
select "inner_id" "id", "inner_name" "name"
from table
where (inner_id = x)
```

Instead of

```
select "inner_id as id", "inner_name as name"
from table
where (inner_id = x)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid quotes around table aliases in jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138434/how-to-avoid-quotes-around-table-aliases-in-jooq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually in the uneccesry quotes.

If anyone else has this error - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138434/how-to-avoid-quotes-around-table-aliases-in-jooq).