# How to configure JOOQ settings using Spring-Boot config?

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I want to tell JOOQ not to quote the identifiers in the SQL it generates as per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28146263/924597

But given I'm letting Spring Boot autoconfigure JOOQ - where do I put this setting?

It seems like the basic spring boot config only supports setting `spring.jooq.sql-dialect` in the `application.properties`, as shown in the [JOOQ-spring-boot-example](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example).

I tried putting `spring.jooq.renderNameStyle=AS_IS` in the `application.properties` but it didn't have any effect on the SQL.

Is there was way customise the Spring boot JOOQ configuration without having to configure JOOQ myself?

I am using SpringBoot 2.1.7.RELEASE and JOOQ 3.11.12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the answer from Lukas worked for configuring the rendering style, but resulted in `JOOQ` no longer participating in `Spring` transaction handling.

Below is the code I've added to my project to customise the identifier rendering.

```java
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.conf.RenderNameStyle;
import org.jooq.conf.Settings;
import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


/**
 Override spring-boot config so JOOQ settings can be customised.
 See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57542573/924597

 Spring-boot config taken from:
 https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-jooq/src/test/java/com/baeldung/jooq/springboot/InitialConfiguration.java
*/
@Component
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {
  @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(
      new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
  }

  @Bean
  public DSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
  }

  public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
    DefaultConfiguration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
    config.set(connectionProvider());
    config.set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
    config.set(new Settings().
      withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS ));
    config.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(
      new JooqExceptionTranslator() ));
    return config;
  }
}
```

**Note**:  The above code appears to work, but results in my IDE telling me that I have multiple beans registered for the `DSLContext` type.  I also added `JooqAutoConfigration` to my list of excluded `spring-boot` auto-config.

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
  SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
  DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
  JooqAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: By the way, to anyone looking up for the solution, look at [DefaultConfigurationCustomizer](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-customise-a-jooq-configuration-that-is-injected-using-spring-boot/). It's a bit more modern and easy, since it has been implemented two years after this answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can also provide a Settings bean (that returns an `org.jooq.conf.Settings` object).

Example that solves the original question:

```
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    Settings jooqSettings() {
        return new Settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);
    }
}
```

The Spring Boot documentation is currently [missing that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#customizing-jooq), but I checked the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/62faab6e60681e90d5ce2ee4280b06de116e7032/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jooq/JooqAutoConfiguration.java#L111) and tested it locally, I have created a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/18870) to fix it.

From spring boot 3.0 you need to use the `DefaultConfigurationCustomizer`, for instance like:

```
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer jooqDefaultConfigurationCustomizer() {
        return c -> c.settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);
    }
}
```

More information is available on the [jooq blog](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-customise-a-jooq-configuration-that-is-injected-using-spring-boot/).

Comment: Thank you for the PR, this will be documented as of Spring Boot 2.1.10 and 2.2.1

Comment: I'm using spring boot 2.6.6 and jooq 3.15.12. This solution works for me.

Comment: Starting with Spring Boot 3.0.0, you should use `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.DefaultConfigurationCustomizer` to customize default jOOQ config.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer to include a Spring Boot 3 example.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Spring Boot 3, the answer provided by Jens wouldn't work anymore, instead one can use `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.DefaultConfigurationCustomizer`, like this (example in Kotlin):

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun jooqConfigurationCustomizer(): DefaultConfigurationCustomizer =
        DefaultConfigurationCustomizer { config ->
            config.setSettings(
                Settings()
                    .withBindOffsetDateTimeType(true)
                    .withRenderQuotedNames(RenderQuotedNames.EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED)
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot is a toolkit to get you *started* with some set of dependencies as quickly as possible. This doesn't mean that you should do *everything* via Spring Boot. Spring Boot cannot possibly maintain a flag corresponding to every single third party library's flag out there.

The reason why spring boot supports `spring.jooq.sql-dialect` is because in some cases, jOOQ cannot auto-detect the dialect from the JDBC `Connection` or `DataSource`, so it is a necessity for Spring Boot to provide that information to jOOQ. The `Settings.renderNameStyle`, on the other hand, is a much more advanced setting that Spring Boot doesn't need to know in order to get a minimal configuration started.

Hence, as soon as you're starting to use more sophisticated library settings / flags, you will need to configure the library yourself. In this case, you could provide the `DSLContext` bean programmatically, or through various other Spring-idiomatic ways, e.g.

```java
@Autowired DataSource ds;

@Bean
public DSLContext ctx() {
    DSL.using(ds, SQLDialect.ORACLE, new Settings().withRenderNameStyle(AS_IS));
}
```

And then inject that `DSLContext` everywhere.

Comment: as noted in my answer, this didn't work for me because of TX handling.  Can you comment if the other answer has any obvious problems?