# jooq DataSourceConnectionProvider with TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy is not taking part in spring transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, jooq, spring-transactions, hikaricp

I have the following spring data source setup:

```
 datasource:
    name: postgres-datasource
    url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb}?reWriteBatchedInserts=true&prepareThreshold=0
    username: ${POSTGRES_USER:mydb}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASS:12345}
    driver-class: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      minimumIdle: 2
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      max-lifetime: 500000
      idleTimeout: 120000
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        useServerPrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 500
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#        generate_statistics: true
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
          batch_size: 50
```

Notice that auto-commit is `false`.
Since, I need to use both jooq and JPA and also have multiple schemas in my db, I have configured the following `DataSourceConnectionProvider`

```
public class SchemaSettingDataSourceConnectionProvider extends DataSourceConnectionProvider {

    public SchemaSettingDataSourceConnectionProvider(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    public Connection acquire() {
        try {
            String tenant = TenantContext.getTenantId();
            log.debug("Setting schema to {}", tenant);
            Connection connection = dataSource().getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("SET SCHEMA '" + tenant + "'");
            statement.close();
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException var2) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Error getting connection from data source " + dataSource(), var2);
        }
    }
```

I have the `@EnableTransactionManagement` on the spring boot config. With this setup in place, the connection is not committing after transaction is over.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public FlowRecord insert(FlowName name, String createdBy) {
        return dslContext.insertInto(FLOW, FLOW.NAME, FLOW.STATUS)
                .values(name.name(), FlowStatus.CREATED.name())
                .returning(FLOW.ID)
                .fetch()
                .get(0);
    }
```

This does not commit. So, I tried adding the following code to my `SchemaSettingDataSourceConnectionProvider` class

```
@Override
    public void release(Connection connection) {
        connection.commit();
        super.release(connection);
    }
```

However, now the issue is that even when a transaction should get rolled back, for e.g due to a runtime exception, it still commits all the time.

Is there some configuration I am missing

**UPDATE**
Following the answer below, I provided a `DataSourceTransactionManager`  bean and it worked for JOOQ.

```
public DataSourceTransactionManager jooqTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        // DSTM is a PlatformTransactionManager
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
```

However, now my regular JPA calls are all failing with

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1692)
```

So, I provided a `JpaTransactionManager` bean. Now this causes JOOQ Auto Configuration to throw multiple DataSourceTransactionManager beans present exception. After much trial and error, the one that worked for me was this:

```
private final TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSource;

    public DslConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        // A transaction aware datasource is needed, otherwise the spring @Transactional is ignored and updates do not work.
        this.dataSource = new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean("transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        // Needed for jpa transactions to work
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Notice that I am using a `JpaTransactionManager` but setting the `datasource` to be `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`. Further testing required, but looks like both JPA and JOOQ transactions are working now.

Comment: On your edit regarding autoconfiguration - on a similar repo (but private), when I was using spring-boot, I disabled the jOOQ auto-config, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634664/924597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to watch out for is to make sure you're using the correct `@Transactional` annotation.  In my project there were two: one from a Jakarta package and one from a Spring package - make sure you're using the Spring annotation.

I don't know if your Spring config is correct.
We use Java config so it's hard to compare.

One obvious difference is that we have an explicit [TransactionManager](https://github.com/au-research/raido-v2/blob/1acc945d33fd1dfb37430e1a787ff87150d9f2b8/api-svc/spring/src/main/java/raido/apisvc/spring/config/database/PrimaryDataSource.java#L65) defined, is that something you maybe need to do?